# Calculating Fourier series in SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, fft

The general solution for heat transport in a metal bar with insulated heads is
[image]

I tried to calculate the gradient at a given time for a typical case where the initial temperature difference is 100 with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
L = 3
n_max = 20

def bn(n):
    n = int(n)
    if (n%2 != 0):
        return 400/(np.pi**2*n**2)
    else:
        return 0

def wn(n):
    global L
    wn = (np.pi*n)/L
    return wn

def fourierSeries(n_max,x,t):
    a0 = 100/2
    partialSums = a0
    for n in range(1,n_max):
            partialSums = partialSums + bn(n)*np.exp(-.00001*wn(n)**2*t)*np.cos(wn(n)*x)
    return partialSums

u = []
for i in x:
    u.append(fourierSeries(n_max,i,1))

plt.plot(x,u)
```

but the result is not what expected
[image]

what is possibly wrong with the code?

Comment: Humm...  long shot...   maybe you are using python2 and all divisions are integer divisions. Are you sure that when you write (np.pi*n)/L for example you get the correct float number as result?

Comment: @Tico yes, it's python 2.7 (via Spyder). What's your suggestion?

Comment: python 2 is weird. Open a shell and write 3/2. It outputs 1.  This notation makes integer division on python2. To do what you expect you should float(3)/float(2) so it understands it as float division and not integer division(or whatever the minds of who did python2 thought to call it when they did this). Python3 fixed this.  3/2 return 1.5 as expected

Comment: Your coefficient is very small. I tried a larger coefficient and also larger time value, and got the expected "sigmoid" shape

Comment: @meowgoesthedog coefficient is a physical parameter. In any case, even if getting sigmoid shape with a larger value, still the y axis, which is the temperature is not right.

Comment: What are you hoping to get? Currently you are plotting only half a period, if you change `x = np.linspace(0,3,100)` to `x = np.linspace(0,30,100)` you will see some pulses.

Comment: If you are waiting for the complete ramp you must add more terms, remember that in this case Fourier is an approximation, the more you add, the more it will look like the original curve.

Comment: @eyllanesc x is between 0 and L. x cannot be larger than the bar length. The curve should show the temperature gradient across the metal bar.

Comment: Specifically, what is the problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc the curve is not realistic. We have a metal bar one end at 100T and the other at 0T. The temperature gradient is between 49.5 and 50.5 at a given time?!? And so much the worse, the curve is time-independent.

Comment: Could you indicate what the temperature variables are besides where did you get the equation?

Comment: Another thing is: do you need to this by yourself (trying to learn)? If you just need results there are a few heat equation solution implementations in python around (http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com.br/2015/07/the-heat-equation-python-implementation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive that you missed the temperature function of the rod:

*f(x) = T + 100/L * x*

Using this, and calculating the integral will do the job.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
L = 3
n_max = 20

def bn(n):
    b=200/n**2/np.pi**2*(np.cos(n*np.pi)-1)
    return b

def wn(n):
    wn = (np.pi*n)/L
    return wn

def fourierSeries(n_max,x,t):
    a0 = 100/2
    partialSums = a0
    for n in range(1,n_max):
        partialSums = partialSums + bn(n)*np.exp(-.0005*wn(n)**2*t)*np.cos(wn(n)*x)
    return partialSums

u = []
hour = 3600
for i in x:
    u.append(fourierSeries(n_max,i,2*hour))

plt.plot(x,u)
```

And the graph:

[image: After 30 minutes one end will have temp=35 and the other end temp=65]

Comment: `bn(n) should calculate the integral in the second equation.

Comment: Yes, because _f(x)_ is in the second equation